# Basic example not working for ffwhich from the ffbase-package

Tags: r, ff, ffbase

I'm trying to use OHDSI:s version of the `SelfControlledCaseSeries` package, which utilizes the `ff` package to handle big data. But something is not working with the `ffwhich` function. Running the following example, provided in the `ffwhich` documentation:

```
install.packages("ff")
install.packages("ffbase")
x <- ff::ff(10:1)
idx <- ffbase::ffwhich(x, x < 5)
```

gives me

```
Error in if (by < 1) stop("'by' must be > 0") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In chunk.default(from = 1L, to = 5L, by = c(integer = 46116860184273880),  :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

I have tried setting `batchbytes` to something smaller, running the script on another computer and also changed the location where ff-files are stored, but the error remains.

```
options("ffbatchbytes"=  getOption("ffmaxbytes")/2)
options(fftempdir="C:/Users/OskarG/Desktop/ff_files")
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar error was reported on the package's [git hub](https://github.com/edwindj/ffbase/issues/57). Appears to be an issue with operating system (Windows 10?). @jwijffels provides the reason in the comments:

> Haven't got windows 10 machine myself but the problem clearly comes from ff::chunk, namely from ff::chunk.ff_vector which is defined as follows
>
> The relevant part is this: b <- BATCHBYTES%/%RECORDBYTES. This calculation apparently on your machine gives 23058430092136940 for reasons beyond my understanding (given that you report it works on Rgui but not on RStudio).
>
> You could probably get around on this by changing option ffbatchbytes to something like this options(ffbatchbytes = 84882227) - which is the number I have on my oldskool windows 7

I was able to reproduce your error and correct it using the above suggestion:

```
library("ff")
library("ffbase")

options(ffbatchbytes = 84882227) #add this line in

x <- ff::ff(10:1)
idx <- ffwhich(x, x < 5)

x[idx][]

[1] 4 3 2 1 #output
```